Ollama isnt using my gpu on a runpod.io pod
I am testing different AI models on runpod.io. One of those models is dolphin-mixtral:8x22b. I followed Runpod's tutorial for setting up the pod with Ollama: https://docs.runpod.io/tutorials/pods/run-ollama, and I used the H100SXM with 80GB VRAM and 16 vCPU 125 GB RAM.
However, when I start the model and ask it something like "hey," it uses 100% of the CPU and 0% of the GPU, and the response takes 5-10 minutes.
How to make Ollama use my GPU?
I tried different server settings

I ran into the same issue, found the answer in this Reddit post.
Set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable to 0,1 before running ollama serve:
:/# export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
:/# echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
0,1
:/# ollama serve

Tested on an A4000 pod.
